# Palindrome ... i think the error is in my if statement because it keeps putting the output as 'it's not'

Tags: java

most likely my error is in the if statement, i want that if the word is not a Palindrome it will display it's not.

```
package palindrome;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Palindrome {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer length;
        Integer lasttofirst = 0;
        Integer firsttolast = 0;
        Boolean result = true;

        String palindrome = ("");
        Scanner inputkey = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        palindrome = inputkey.nextLine();
        char[] newWord = palindrome.toCharArray();
        length = palindrome.length();

        System.out.println("The length is: " + length);

        if (newWord[firsttolast] == newWord[lasttofirst]) {
            firsttolast = lasttofirst + 1;
        }

        if (firsttolast == lasttofirst) {
            lasttofirst = firsttolast + 1;
            // result = true;
        }

        if (newWord[lasttofirst] == newWord[firsttolast]) {
            firsttolast = lasttofirst + 1;
            System.out.println("It is a palindrome ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" it's not");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't reliably compare `Integer`s with `==`. Use `int` instead. With `Integer`, you need to use `.equals()`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? He may not know a few concepts/conventions but from the code he posted, it seems like he's at least trying...

Comment: @sparky, "most likely my error is in the if statement"; there's three `if`s. Plus, just saying it doesn't work isn't really sufficient for quality (although that won't stop answers); they should explain what is wrong with it. Give input and output examples and so forth. That being said, I wasn't a down-voter.

Answer (score 1):

You start with:

```
Integer lasttofirst = 0;
Integer firsttolast = 0;
```

and you check:

```
if (newWord[firsttolast] == newWord[lasttofirst])
```

which will always be true; so you then set:

```
firsttolast = lasttofirst + 1;
```

and check:

```
if (firsttolast == lasttofirst)
```

which will always be false (since `1 != 0`) and finally you check if:

```
if (newWord[lasttofirst] == newWord[firsttolast])
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
if (newWord[0] == newWord[1])
```

so, it will be true if the first two characters are the same.

*The conclusion is:* you aren't checking if its a palindrome at all, all you are doing is checking the first two characters.

I would do something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
    public static boolean isPalindrome( final String string ){
        if ( string == null )
            return false;
        for ( int i = 0, j = string.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j-- ){
            if ( string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(j) )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        String input;
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        while ( (input = scanner.nextLine()).length() > 0 ){
            System.out.println( isPalindrome( input ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth:

1. You need a loop to solve this problem.
2. Use int rather than Integer
3. Format your code to make it readable.
4. Use i++ to increment an integer and i-- to decrement.
5. Use camel case for variables `lastToFirst`. It is the Java way.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see where he's incrementing or decrementing variables.

Comment: @KSFT Inside the if statements, `firsttolast = lasttofirst + 1`

Comment: @sparky that's different from any use of ++

Comment: @ecarlos Oops. Yeah you're right. I just glanced at it without thinking about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the StringBuilder class's reverse() method to reverse a Java String.

Then compare the two using String's equals();

```
String rPalindrome = new StringBuilder(palindrome).reverse().toString();

if(palindrome.equals(rPalindrome))
  System.out.println("It is a palindrome ");
else
  System.out.println(" it's not");
```

But with this you would still have issues with casing (uppercase and lowercase) and so you could use String's .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase() methods to eliminate that problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a sub-optimal, but elegant solution you can use recursion

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return false;
    if (s.length() < 2)
        return true;
    return s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1) && isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
}
```